# Android selector with urls

Tags: android

Now,I have multiple RadioButtons with internet url resource,and I need to set a selector for the RadioButton with two urls returned from server.
I've thought to change url resource when the RadioButton state changed,but I think that too complex. 
Is there anybody who can help me.

[image]

Pictured above, under normal circumstances, we put in the selector drawable is from local resources, now state 1 is normal, state 2 is elections, but two pictures are loaded network

Comment: elaborate your question....

Comment: also post some of your efforts....